# In spark standalone mode is the master and executors located in a single machine?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-standalone

Does spark standalone mode means that the executors and master  are run on a single machine?If yes how can it attend parallelism. 
Is the value passed to set local function of spark conf set as one in standalone mode to indicate that spark application is running on single machine?

Answer (score 2):

*"Does spark standalone mode means that the executors and master are run on a single machine?"* => No.

"standalone" in "spark standalone mode" does not mean a single machine. In Spark Standalone mode, typically there are multiple slave nodes. Spark Standalone mode is another cluster mode like Mesos and Yarn. Please refer to https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/spark-standalone.html in detail.

I guess you are asking "Local Mode". Spark runs in Local Mode if you execute like `spark-shell --master=local[4]`. In this case, spark driver and executors run on a single JVM and has multiple threads.

You can find many answers about "Spark Local Mode" if you google it.

Comment: so does local[4] means one master and three slaves ie; one driver and three executors. And so parallelism is attained since this threads are executed parallel.

Comment: @Anu *"so parallelism is attained since this threads are executed parallel"* => Yes. "*local[4] means one master and three slaves"* => Just 1 driver with 4 cores on a single JVM. After executing `$ spark-shell --master=local[4]`, visit http://localhost:4040/ and click "Executors" menu, then you can see information. If you run some spark job, you can see how many cores are working via "Active tasks" on Spark Web UI.